# How to get the 5 highest values trough linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq

I have a database of books.

```
ID                    TimesRead
1                     45
2                     12
3                     84
4                     1
5                     17
6                     65
7                     4
8                     98
9                     42
10                    14
```

How do i get the 5 most read books trough linq ?

In this case it would be `id= 8,3,6,1,9`.

Answer (score 1):

```
from m in MyTable
orderby TimesRead descending
take 5
select m
```

Or

```
Mytable.OrderByDesc(x => x.TimesRead).take(5);
```

Comment: and also really need to select ID, to get 8,3,6,1,9

Comment: @CodeUniquely, you need select these Ids or you need a function to get the top 5 books ?

Comment: Updated my answer. CodeUniquely, you should not ask for syntax here - there is a bunch of links in google

Comment: Not asking for Syntax  - I was pointing out a The OP asked for LINQ that returned ID's, to quote  ' ... in this case it would be id = 8,3,6,1,9 '. The answer posted returns Book not ID therefore there should be a select for ID added to the answer given.

Answer (score 1):

User ta.speot.is placed a very smart remark: what about ties? Or, what if book #10 also had 42 reads (like 9). It wouldn't be fair to drop it out of the league, would it? In its most extreme form, what if all books had the same amount of reads?

Let's assume it's the five highest *reads* you're interested in. Then you should group by `TimesRead` and report the five highest groups with their books (any number):

```
var readGroups = from b in books
                 group b by b.TimesRead into readgroup
                 select new 
                     { 
                         TimesRead = readgroup.Key, 
                         Books = string.Join(", ", readgroup.Select(b => b.Id))
                     };
var highFive = readGroups.Take(5);
```

this will give you an output like

```
98  8
84  3
65  6
45  1
42  9
```

but if 10 also had 42 reads:

```
98  8
84  3
65  6
45  1
42  9, 10
```

and if all had the same # reads:

```
42  1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Use OrderByDescending() and Take() extension methods for IEnumerable/IQueryable results you get from DB, then use Select() to get only fields you need